# How to differentiate between Stay On Page and Leave Page

Tags: javascript, browser, dom-events

In JavaScript when beforeunload event is executed and the warning box pops up, is it possible to get information what button was clicked?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this directly unfortunately as `onbeforeunload` asks the browser to create the dialog and doesn't tell you the return value but you can use a global variable which you set in the event and check it via `setInterval` for example.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/txwLLepk/5/)

```
var confirmUnload = false;

window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(event) {
    confirmUnload = true;
    event.returnValue = "Really leave?";
});

window.addEventListener("unload", function(event) {
    console.log("User left");
});

setInterval(function(){
    if(confirmUnload) {
        confirmUnload = false;

        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('Still here');
        }, 500);
    }
}, 400);
```